# How to get file location in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, address

How to get file location of this page in magento 1.9
[image]

Comment: You can enable the template path hints from magento admin. Then you can see the template file location.

Answer (score 1):

As Bare Feet said enabling path hints helps a lot when trying to find file locations.

However, for this particular file, if I recall correctly, it should be either at:

> app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/customer/form/address.phtml

or at

> app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Best option to do is enabling template path hints.

To enable path hints:

1. Login to Magento Admin panel
2. Go to System->Configuration.
3. The Template Path and Block name will only appear for current website. So change the Current Configuration Scope to ‘Main Website’.
4. Go to the Advanced section and click on Developers.
5. Expand the Debug tab.
6. Set the Template Path Hints to ‘Yes’.
7. Click on ‘Save Configuration’ button.

If your website is in production, you can also restrict the hints by IP.